# php is not working with all $_POST in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a problem where $_POST is working ("Undefined index"), only the last 4 variables that keep working, please help.

For help:

1- I'm using 4 modals there id's=MyModal1,2,3,4, each modal has his own submit button.

2- the last 4 Posts are placed in the last modal id=MyModal4 and I think because of it the other $_POSTS don't work (submit only the last modal).

3- each modal body has his own form

4- for full use you must fill all the field

5- each modal body has his own Form with methode=Post

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 
<?php

  $date=date('Y-m-d');
  $date3=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . "+3 months") );
  $date6=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . "+6 months") );
  $date12=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . "+12 months") );
 



  ?>
  
     <?php
     

      
   
        
      $nom=$_POST['nom_client'];
      $prenom=$_POST['pernomclient'];
      $date_naissance=$_POST['datenaiss'];
      $lieu_naissance=$_POST['lieunaiss'];
      $commune=$_POST['commune'];
      $dayra=$_POST['daira'];
      $willaya=$_POST['wilaya'];
      $proffession=$_POST['proffesion'];

      


        
          $Num_per=$_POST['numpermis'];
      $date_obt=$_POST['dateobt'];
      $date_deliv=$_POST['delivre'];
     

        
      
          $date_eff=$_POST['effet'];
          $date_exp=$_POST['expiration'];
          
      

          $numserie=$_POST['numserie'];
          $type=$_POST['typevoi'];
          $marque=$_POST['marque'];
          $aces_asies=$_POST['acesass'];
          $num_matricul=$_POST['immatricul'];
        
echo $nom;
      echo $prenom;
      echo $date_naissance;
      echo $lieu_naissance;
      echo $commune;
      echo $dayra;
      echo $willaya;
      echo $proffession;
 echo $Num_per;
      echo $date_obt;
      echo $date_deliv;     
      echo $date_eff;
      echo $date_exp;
          echo $numserie;
          echo $type;
          echo $marque;
          echo $aces_asies;
          echo $num_matricul;
     
  
 
              ?>

    <title>assurence</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assurance1css.css">

</head>


<body>
 <div>
  <form method="POST">
<div class="button">
  <img src="lll.jpg" class="rounded" width="170px" height="170px">

    <button type="submit" name="suivantn" class="btn button1 " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

      Nouveau-Client
     </button>
  
      <button type="button" class="btn button1 " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Ancien Client
     </button>

</div>

 

   <!-- information de client -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
    
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Informations personnelle </h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <form  method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          
            <p> --------------------------------------------------------- </p>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Mr
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Meme
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="unknown" > Melle
<p> --------------------------------------------------------- </p>
                        

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Nom  du client:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer le Nom  du client" name="nom_client"  required >

    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Prenom du client :</label>
 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateverif" placeholder="Entrer le Prenom du client" name="pernomclient"  required >
  
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Date de naissance :</label>

    <input type="Date" class="form-control" id="datefin" placeholder=" " name="datenaiss" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"
 required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Lieu de naissance:</label>
 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer le Lieu de naissance" name="lieunaiss"  required >
 
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>



 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Commune du client:</label>
    
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer la Commune du client" name="commune"  required >
 
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Daira du client:</label>
 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer la Daira du client" name="daira"  required >
  
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Willaya du client:</label>
   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer la Willaya du client" name="wilaya"  required >
 
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Sa proffesion:</label>
   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer Sa proffesion" name="proffesion"  required >
 
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>


<script>
// Disable form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('a été validé');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
        </div>
       
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h4 class="modal-title text-left "> .</h4>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name="suivant1" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal2" >Suivant</button>
        </div>
    </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <!-- Permis -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal2">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Permis :</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
      <form method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <!-- Modal body -->
        
        <div class="modal-body">
          
                        

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">NUM-Permi:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer le NUM-Permi" name="numpermis"  required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Date Obtention :</label>
    <input type="Date" class="form-control" id="dateverif" placeholder=" " name="dateobt"   required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>


    
  
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Deliver le :</label>
    <input type="Date" class="form-control" id="datefin" placeholder=" " name="delivre"  required="" >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

<div>
  <p><u><strong> Permis Categorie</strong></u> </p>
<select >
            <option id="one"><strong>Type A </strong></option>
            <option id="two"><strong>Type B </strong></option>
            <option id="three"><strong>Type C </strong></option>
        </select>



</div>





<script>
// Disable form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('a été validé');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <h4 class="modal-title text-left "> .</h4>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name="suivant2" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Suivant</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="modal" id="myModal3">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      




        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Durée :</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

        </div>
         <form  method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">

         
                    

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Durée :</label>
    <select onclick="modal1()" id="durée">
  <option value="volvo">3mois</option>
  <option value="saab">6mois</option>
  <option value="mercedes">12mois</option>
  
</select>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Effet:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eff" name="effet"  required readonly>
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Expiration</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exp"  name="expiration"  required readonly >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
</div>




<script>
// Disable form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('a été validé');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>

 </div>

        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <h4 class="modal-title text-left "> .</h4>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="suivant3" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal4" >Suivant</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="modal" id="myModal4">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Information de voiture:</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <form  method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>

            <div class="modal-body">
          
                    

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">NUM-dans la serie du type :</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer NUM-dans la serie du type " name="numserie"  required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Type :</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dateverif" placeholder="Entrer type d voiture" name="typevoi"  required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Marque :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateverif" placeholder="Entrer la marque " name="marque"  required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Aces assise:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dateverif" placeholder="Entrer nmbr d places" name="acesass"  required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Energie:</label>
    <select >
            <option id="ess" value="Ess"><strong>Ess</strong></option>
            <option id="gaz" value="Gaz"><strong>Gaz</strong></option>
            <option id="dsl" value="Dsl"><strong>Dsl</strong></option>
        </select>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Num d'immatriculation:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dateverif" placeholder="Entrer Num d'immatriculation" name="immatricul"  required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>


<script>
// Disable form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('a été validé');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
</div>
<!-- Modal footer -->

        <div class="modal-footer">
         

          <h4 class="modal-title text-left "> .</h4>
          
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  name="enregistrer">Enregistrer</button>
         
        </div>

        </form>

        

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
function modal1() {
  var select=document.getElementById('durée');
  var strUser = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  if(strUser=="volvo"){
    document.getElementById("eff").defaultValue = "<?php echo $date;?>";
document.getElementById("exp").defaultValue = "<?php echo $date3;?>";
}
else if(strUser=="saab"){
  document.getElementById("eff").defaultValue = "<?php echo $date;?>";
document.getElementById("exp").defaultValue = "<?php echo $date6;?>";
}
else if(strUser=="mercedes"){
  document.getElementById("eff").defaultValue = "<?php echo $date;?>";
document.getElementById("exp").defaultValue = "<?php echo $date12;?>";
}
}


</script>


</form>
</div>


</body>





</html>
```

Comment: You can only submit one form at a time, and `$_POST` will only contain the fields from the current submission.

Comment: @Barmar so i must delete all forms and make one global ?

Comment: You could copy the inputs from Modals 1-3 to hidden inputs in Modal 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery ajax to achieve this. Sample code given below

```
<!-- include JQuery if not added already -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('#myModal1 form, #myModal2 form, #myModal3 form, #myModal4 form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url  : '',
        type : 'POST',
        data : $('#myModal1 form, #myModal2 form, #myModal3 form, #myModal4 form').serialize(),
        success : function() {
            window.location = '';
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: thnx i was searching for ajax script but i couldn't find the exact one